# How to perform molecular dynamics simulations of charged systems?

Tags: reference-request, software, molecular-mechanics, molecular-dynamics

The GROMACS official documentation (see [here](http://www.gromacs.org/Documentation/Errors#System_has_non-zero_total_charge)) states that a system with non-zero total charge will yield an error:

> **System has non-zero total charge**
>
> Notifies you that counter-ions may be required for the system to neutralize the charge or there may be problems with the topology.
>
> If the charge is a non-integer, then this indicates that there is a problem with the topology. If pdb2gmx has been used, then look at the right hand comment column of the atom listing, which lists the cumulative charge. This should be an integer after every residue (and/or charge group where applicable). This will assist in finding the residue where things start departing from integer values. Also check the capping groups that have been used.
>
> If the charge is already close to an integer, then the difference is caused by rounding errors and not a major problem.
>
> Note for PME users: It is possible to use a uniform neutralizing background charge in PME to compensate for a system with a net background charge. There is probably nothing wrong with this in principle, because the uniform charge will not perturb the dynamics. Nevertheless, it is standard practice to actually add counter-ions to make the system net neutral.

If I understand this correctly, it means that a uniform background charge will be added to a net-charged system. What if I wanted to study a charged system, e.g. a peptide with basic groups *in the gas phase*, where counter ions are absent. Is it still possible to perform a gromacs calculation on such a system and how will the introduction of the compensating background charge affect the molecular dynamics?

I then looked into other packages and noted that net-charged systems seem to be generally problematic in mm calculations. Can anyone point me into a direction like literature on this?

Comment: A system with net charge is not stable - electrostatic repulsion will make it fly apart. That would seem to be fairly problematic, no?

Comment: @JonCuster I am not sure if I understand correctly what you mean: there are *tons* of systems with a net charge that are incredibly stable. For example, ammonium is a stable ion, a "molecule" with a net charge. In mass spectrometry, you always observe all kinds of molecules with a net charge. So, molecules with a net charge don't fly apart.

Comment: @JonCuster Then, when I do MD simulations with semi empirical or *ab initio* methods, handling of the charge is no problem. The system does not "fly apart",
so I guess you meant to say that molecules with a net charge can not be handled by MM methods, as in MM methods, they will fly apart due to the electrostatic repulsion term. Right?

Comment: A single charged molecule will not fly apart, most likely. Trying to simulate two protons with no electrons will cause you a few problems. So, you need to clarify what your 'system' is since the program is not sentient (yet). If I were writing the documentation, I would probably say something similar - if the user doesn't balance charge on some arbitrary input, the program will do so since it cannot understand what the user really wants to get at.

Comment: @JonCuster Then let's say the system is lysin in charge state  +1. It is stable, otherwise biology would be very unhappy right now. Can gromacs (or any mm for that matter) handle it without adding an unwanted compensating background charge?

Comment: (Note - I'm just a simple materials scientist - I have no idea what a lysine molecule actually looks like!). I'll ask this question - in biology is the lysine(+1) isolated, or is it in solution? If it is in solution, isn't the system (molecule + surroundings) net neutral? I would think there is an OH- hanging around somewhere? What I do know is various mod/sim techniques have real problems modeling charged defects in solids, and an even harder time modeling charge capture/emission from said defects. Convergence can be very hard in those situations.

Comment: @JonCuster I agree. But isolated charged systems really aren't that exotic. E.g. in mass spectrometry, you will observe them all the time. But most MM/MD systems are laid out for solution state ...

Comment: The target for most (all?) MD software is biochem and/or materials science, so calculating isolated single molecules charged or not is not their main focus. Your best chance for calculations with periodic boundary condition is using PME or an artificial counterion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is intrinsic to Ewald summation methods, not software implementations. The uniform charge arises from neglect of a reciprocal sum term. It does not directly affect the dynamics and may be a reasonable model of a spatially homogeneous system. See https://mailman-1.sys.kth.se/pipermail/gromacs.org_gmx-users/2015-October/101544.html for further details and https://www.mpibpc.mpg.de/14063977/Hub_2014_JCTC.pdf for a description and explanation of the likely artefacts.

Comment: I also suspected that it has something to do with the mm calculation, but that really made it clear. Thanks!

Comment: You can also correct for the net charge post simulation

Comment: How would you change the sampling after the fact?

Comment: @mabraham sorry, I didn't get notified you commented, and just saw this randomly. Check out https://sourceforge.net/p/towhee/mailman/message/24030424/. A good question would be... what kind of sampling are you setting yourself up for by putting in an explicit counter ion as is often done? how does that not skew sampling?

Comment: I could imagine such a correction working for e.g. chemical potential. The OP's problem suits using a charged system and they should just do that. However, many cases do not suit that treatment - the sampling of a water box with four chlorides will differ whether four explicit counter ions are present, or not, and so many observable properties will not be able to be corrected by a general correction term.